# My audio control showing, but it not playing

Tags: audio

It just doesn't play.
This is the code for the player:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="https://www.reportercatolico.com.br/audios/1cd5d4f1448ae07340406213d5da61dc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let me guess, you probably do not have an mp3 decoder on your platform?

Comment: Works for me...